# How to use solver with more complex systems of equations?

Tags: excel, solver

I have these equations

```
A=175+10E5+E5            A
0.196A=10D+0.400D        B
0.45C=175                C
0.804A+0.600E=C          D
A+E=B+C                  E
B=F                      F
C=175+G                  G
```

and I need to solve them with solver. I have tried splitting them up and messing with solver settings, but I have no idea how to properly set up solver in excel to work with this.

Comment: Do you want to solve the specific system of equations of a generalised approach?

Comment: Also on your first line why did you enter `10E5+E5` instead of `11*E5` or `10*10^5 + 10^5`, or even `11*10^5` - it isn't clear if this is a cell reference or exponential notation.